# Abstract targets in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have 6 targets and 1 dependency in my make rule. The target files have the following names when produced:

- mm10.1.ebwt
- mm10.2.ebwt
- mm10.3.ebwt
- mm10.4.ebwt
- mm10.rev.1.ebwt
- mm10.rev.2.ebwt

Is there anyway I can forgo listing all of these separately in the rule? For instance is there anyway I can specify two general files like so:

```
mm10.[1-4].ebwt mm10.rev.[1-2].ebwt: mm10.fa
    # build genome index
    bowtie-build $^
```

Edit for kebs:

On the command line running the following command:

bowtie build mm10.fa

will result in six files being produced with prefix mm10:

mm10.1.ebwt, mm10.2.ebwt, mm10.3.ebwt, mm10.4.ebwt, mm10.rev.1.ebwt, mm10.rev.2.ebwt

I would like to abstract the specific names to create a make rule for bowtie build, but listing each file produced results in a long line, I was wondering if there was a way to make it neater by defining a range of filenames produced.

Comment: Unclear to me. The sample you show does not seem to be valid. Instead of trying to show what the solution could look like, tell us (edit the question) what output you expect.

Comment: If no other targets depend on these files, there's no reason to list them at all; you can have a PHONY target (e.g. `all`) or a "make anything" target (`%`) which will build all six without Make knowing about them.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the point. What I have understood: 1-you have some program (`bowtie-build`) that generates 6 output files when called with one input file as argument. 2 - you are searching for a way `to create a make rule for bowtie build`. Are you trying to **build** this program ? Seems that no. Either the question is ill-formulated, either you missed the whole point on what `make` is all about. (which I don't think either, so I'm puzzled...)

Comment: @kebs Sorry, I should have stated that I am using makefiles as a way to string together small scripts/programs, shown [here](http://www.bioinformaticszen.com/post/decomplected-workflows-makefiles/)